# Simple html_dom_parser not working in Internet explorer

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, domparser

I am trying to parse a html webpage. It is working properly in Chrome, but fails in Internet Explorer 10;

This is my code:

```
//the content variable is a string with the html markup
$html = str_get_html($content);
$element = $html->find('div[style="width: 460px; padding-bottom: 20px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666666;"]', 0);
$tmp = $element->plaintext;
print($tmp);die();
```

in google chrome i get the result i want, simply the plain text that is inside the element that i am parsing with the find() method. In internet explorer i get an empty result. Seems that it is not finding the specific element.

if, for example i do this:

```
foreach ($html->find('img') as $img) {
    $pre[] = $img->src;
}
print_r($pre);die();
```

i get the result i want both in chrome and in internet explorer. (returns the src attribute of all images in the string)

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: "*messes something up*" is not a very good description of the problem. What is the actual issue here? What is the output that you expect? How does it differ in IE? Does the actual generated page differ in any way? (use "view source" to check). What rendering mode is IE displaying it with? (use the F12 dev tools to check).

Comment: @Spudley i am using source to check. I am expexcting a plain text that is inside the element that i am parsing with $html->find() method;

i get no errors. it seems that it's not finding the specific element.

Comment: So what are you getting in IE then? Are you getting the wrong value? Part of the value? Nothing at all? Where is the `$content` file coming from? Is it an HTML doc that is sent from the browser?

Comment: in ie i get an empty result. The $content is a string of html markup. I tried puting contents in a file and parsing that file, still the same thing: Good result in Chrome, nothing in Ie...

Comment: the $content is coming via Ajax base_64 encoded. I decode the string and parse it. I works on Chrome, bot fails in IE.

Comment: So I guess the content is coming in differently between the two browsers. Is it being generated by a browser-based editor like ckEditor? If so, yes, there's a strong probability that the browsers will generate different code, particularly for something like that; there's no way you can control the order it will generate the styles. Try looking at the code generated in `$content`, and comparing it; you may need to re-think how you load the element (maybe give it class instead of inline styles?).

Comment: @Spudley i found out part of the problem.
It seems that IE changes the hexazecimal color (#00000) in rgb (0, 0, 0). And that is why i don't get any output, because it cannot find that element.

Comment: @Spudley i don't have access to the page that i am parsing... I am geting the contents of an iframe page.

Comment: Well, you're going to have to find some other method of parsing it, because as you've discovered, the method you're using is extremely brittle. One possible option might be to use [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) to parse it, though you'll still have the same issue if you're trying to parse based on the style attribute. Does the parent element have a class or ID you can reference more reliably?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Internet Explorer replaces the hex value of the color (ex: `#666666`) with the rgb value of it (`rgb(102, 102, 102)`). So i had to make a special case for IE.

Comment: It is obvious though, PHP is nothing to do with browser. That's why many people calls it "server-side".

Comment: Yes, PHP has nothing to do with browser, but it searches the DOM for whatever it is you are looking for. And IE instead of showing hex value(#666666) like chrome or firefox does, it is showing RGB value. And it does not return a match.